# Sort sub array descending (or create it in another mode)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm getting, for pagination, previous (if they exists) 5 page respect of current page.

```
        $k = 0;
        for ($i=$requested_page-1;$i>=1;$i--) {

            if ($k<$range_pagination) {

                $result['range_pagination']['under'][] = $i;

            }
            $k++;

        }
```

But array resulting is:

```
array(2) {
    ["under"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      int(14)
      [1]=>
      int(13)
      [2]=>
      int(12)
      [3]=>
      int(11)
      [4]=>
      int(10)
    }[...]
```

Printing them in HTML results in not-so-beautiful way

[image]

But must be

[image]

I did try

```
rsort($result['range_pagination']['under']);
```

without change.

So, how can I sort the array OR create in another way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do this?

```
for ($i=$requested_page-5;$i<=$requested_page;$i++) {
    if ($i >= 1  && $i < $range_pagination)
    {
        $result['range_pagination']['under'][] = $i;
    }
}
```

You'll need the `$range_pagination` to make sure it won't echo more pages than it has. It put it there assuming this is your `total_pages` number

This will output, for example, if your `$requested_page` equals 20,

> 15 16 17 18 19 **20**

This could make it look better:

```
for ($i=$requested_page-2;$i<=$requested_page+2;$i++) {
    if ($i >= 1  && $i <= $range_pagination)
    {
        if ($i == $requested_page)
            echo "<b> " . $i . " </b>";
        else
            echo " " . $i . " ";
    }
}
```

It will look like this: https://ideone.com/dH3tM0

The output would be, for page 1:

> **1** 2 3

page 10:

> 8 9 **10** 11 12

last page

> 28 29 **30**

Comment: We are not so far from solution, but your code for page "3" print also -1 and -2 and 0 (we don't need zero or negative)

Comment: @sineverba take a look

Comment: You could make it better by putting the current page in the middle instead of the end.

Comment: thank you for your observation; current is already in the middle. There is another array with "range over" ;-) But, another one time, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$k = 0;
for ($i=$requested_page-1;$i>=1;$i--) {

    if ($k<$range_pagination) {

        $result['range_pagination']['under'][] = $i;

    }
    $k++;

}
asort($result['range_pagination']['under']);
```

Comment: If I'm on page 19, array need to give 18,17,16,15,14. If we are on page 57, array need to be 56,55,54,53,52.

Comment: then use asort instead of rsort

Comment: Your code print page from 1 to 5, also if we are on page 1547. But thank you ;)

Comment: you can use asort after your for loop

`$k = 0;
        for ($i=$requested_page-1;$i>=1;$i--) {

            if ($k<$range_pagination) {

                $result['range_pagination']['under'][] = $i;

            }
            $k++;

        }`

Answer (score 0):

Make change into your for statement like:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$requested_page;$i++){}
```

Just for suggestion, here is some simple pagination code that you can use with Bootstrap.
[php-mysql-pagination](http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/php-mysql-pagination)

This source have fully demonstrate with CSS style and php code snippet.

Comment: I don't think he wants al the pages, only the last 5.

Comment: Your code print page from 1 to 5, also if we are on page 1547. But thank you ;)